# setup mongoose with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm currently using MongoDB with nodejs, so i'm struggling to use save method, it returns promise pending if there's anyone who can help me to fix I will be thankful.
this my code :

> booking.js:

```
var express = require("express");
const Booking = require("../model/booking");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/booking", async (req, res) => {
  const booking = new Booking({
    address: req.body.address,
    name: req.body.name,
    latitude: req.body.latitude,
    longitude: req.body.longitude
  });
  try {
    const savedBooking = await booking.save();
    console.log(savedBooking);
    res.json(savedBooking);
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({ message: e });
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

> /module/booking.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bookingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    default: "khalil"
  },

    address:String,
    name:String ,
    latitude: String,
    longitude: String


});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Booking", bookingSchema);
```

Comment: Which `mongoose` version are you using?

Comment: i'm using this version 5.6.9, bro

Comment: Do you use `babel`? Your code looks like it should be working. Are you using a custom promise library? You might need to explicitly specify the promise implementation: `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise`

Comment: NO i don't use babel, ok i will try to add this piece of code to my code .thank u bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read request parameters from a **get** method, which doesn't have a body. Change your 'booking.js' code like:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Booking = require("../model/booking");

router.post("/booking", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {
            address,
            name,
            latitude,
            longitude
        } = req.body;
        const booking = new Booking({
            address,
            name,
            latitude,
            longitude,
        });
        const savedBooking = await booking.save();
        console.log(savedBooking);
        return res.status(200).json(savedBooking);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error is: => ', err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and then you can call it like as a http **post** method with the JSON payload in body.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in getting the request params. You're using a GET request and trying to get data off the request body but a GET request only has params, not a body. Either change it to a POST or change your data to `req.params.address`

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function to `log` booking object. Remember remove `async` in `async (req, res)`.

```js
try {
    booking.save(function (err, booking) {
      const savedBooking = booking;
      console.log(savedBooking);
      res.json(savedBooking);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({ message: e });
}
```